# Need you to tell me the fact

Tags: grammar

I saw a sentence in a movie Big Fish.  One sentence of it says: "I need you to tell me that I'm not crazy".

Originally, I understood the sentence as:

> "I want you to tell the fact that I'm a sane person to me."
>
> *YOU tell the fact to ME. crazy=insane*

But some books translate it as:

> "I am required to tell you the fact that I'm not pissed off."
>
> *I tell the fact to YOU. crazy=mad at*

Which one is right? And how can I understand the nicety of the usage of the verb: NEED?

Plus, how could you distinguish the meaning of CRAZY? Just depending on the context?

Comment: *Crazy* never means angry with someone. Only *mad* has both senses.

Comment: @tchrist I tend to agree. However, people will sometimes say *when he found out that his watch had been stolen, he went absolutely crazy*. Now that doesn't mean 'insane', does it?

Comment: @WS2 it does mean "insane with anger", which is the point of coining it, I believe. Nevertheless, one would not use that sense in "I'm telling you I'm not angry". Or at least, I've never seen it used that way.

Comment: @WS2 I think it might: a berserker rage is a form of irrational nuttiness.

Comment: *"He is mad"* can mean either of *"He is insane"* or *"He is angry"*. But *"He is crazy"* always means "insane" to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Actually, "He is crazy" could mean that he's really funny, but that's a just metaphor based on the "insane" meaning.

Comment: There’s also the infatuated *crazy* (crazy *about* someone). Context is key to disambiguation here.

Answer (score 5):

The second translation is incorrect, and would not be considered as an option by a native speaker.  You should probably mistrust whatever source you found it in.

In general, "need" is sometimes used when "want" is probably more accurate --it's a stronger word, and expresses that what is being spoken about is not just a desire but a necessity (whether or not that is technically true).

"Mad" and "crazy" can both mean insane, but "mad" has a second, more common meaning of "angry" while "crazy" does not.  As mentioned in the comments, one can be crazy with anger, but in that case, the anger is the source of the craziness, and not synonymous with it.